# What's the difference between "чашка" and "кружка"?

Tags: значения, разница

When I try googling *кружка*, I don't get anything that resembles a cup, but it's the first choice when I use Google Translate.

Comment: Google translate should not be trusted too much. *Кружка* is closer to a mug. Try to google *кружка* and click "Images", you should see better examples.

Comment: "чашка" is more rounded on the bottom, it's in general more spherical

Comment: кружка is higher, more cylindrical.

Comment: really, the best answer here will be showing the pictures. 
Кружка : ______   
https://ireland.apollo.olxcdn.com/v1/files/im8m0x8h984o1-UA/image;s=525x700     
    
https://static.baza.farpost.ru/v/1595091673236_bulletin
    
Чашка :
____
  https://images.vitber.com/product_main_v2/product/5c63ea4a5af07.JPG

чашки are more small and more flat.

Answer (score 10):

Theoretically, *чашка* would be an almost complete analogue to the English *cup*, while *кружка* is closer to a *mug*.

Indeed the origin of the word *чаша* (of which *чашка* is a variation/descendant) is usually traced to Proto-Slavic *čаšа* (according to Max Vasmer's etymological dictionary), which is related to Old Prussian *kiosi*, meaning a *goblet* or *chalice*: a cup. Even in modern Russian *чаша* may be used to poetically refer to that kind of a vessel.

The similarity of *cup* and *чашка* can also be seen in other terms. For example, the bra cups are usually referred to as *чашечки* (a diminutive of *чашка*) in Russian terminology.

There are a couple of irregularities, though.

For one, in the geometrical sense, *чаша* is used to refer to any bowl-shaped object. For instance, when referring to a crater, English is more likely to classify it as a *bowl-shaped* depression, where is Russian term would be *чашеобразный* (in fact, the insides of the crater are even scientifically called *чаша кратера*).

Another one is a bit more practical. As @Curiosity mentioned, when talking specifically about disposable plastic/paper cups, the ones shaped like a handle-free glass, Russian uses the word *стакан* (glass). The ones shaped like a cup with a handle would still be called a cup, however.

On the other hand, *кружка* is pretty much exclusively used for *mug*, or *tankard*, or even *stein*.

With that in mind, when you are talking about modern-day drinking vessels, you can safely use *чашка*/*чашечка* in place of a *cup* and *кружка*/*кружечка* in place of a *mug*.

That being said, pottery/woodwork/metalwork is wild, and there are obviously certain edge-cases where the difference between *cup*/*чашка* and *mug*/*кружка* is uncertain at best, and I would hesitate to guarantee that both languages and associated cultures would classify every object the same way.

Comment: I wouldn't say you can safely use чашка in place of a cup. A cup often refers to a glass, or a paper/plastic cup of similar shape. That would be called стакан in Russian.

Comment: Do you really mean you personally call a pottery mug for tea _кружка_? Isn't _кружка_ used exclusively for metal cylindrical ones? In my idiolect  _кружка_ can be only made of metal, the only exception being glass/pottery/wooden/tin beer tankards which are also _кружка_.

Comment: To tell the truth, I'm not interested in how they call the items in stores, I asked about you personally. You know, in the 1980s in all the Soviet stores on price tags, T-shirts were called _фуфайка_ (sic!), but I've never seen a single person using that word to call T-shirts, everybody said _футболка_. Yandex is inaccessible from my country, but I believe you. Still, do _you_ ever call cups _кружка_?

Answer (score 3):

The difference between чашка and кружка, as a kind of vessel for a liquid to drink or pour from it, is rather subtle and is better expressed in pictures:

[This](https://dokuhni.ua/images/uploads/user_files/461/chashka-farforovaya-belaya-lotos-v-sort-siecta-91230-tm-farn.jpg) is чашка but never кружка. So, if a cup has apparently narrower bottom than top, and provided with a saucer, it canʼt be кружка.

[This](https://www.al-group.com.ua/image/cache/catalog/GenWare/50018RED-550x550-product_thumb.jpg) is кружка but never чашка. We donʼt use чашка for a cylindrical metal vessel (typical tourist equipment).

[This](https://images.ua.prom.st/1270242569_w640_h640_belaya-chashka-apple.jpg) is both чашка and кружка. It is a faience or porcelain cylindrical vessel with a handle. What word is used, it may be even regional (according to my observings, кружка is more used for it in northern regions, but чашка - in southern; but this is definitely not strict).

Also, both words are used for vacuum flask ("thermos") cap provided for drinking from it.

Also, one should take into account that for some vessels, стакан is preferred, mainly for high, narrow vessel without a handle and which form is close to cylinder, maybe with slight widening to top; it is typically of glass or plastic.

There are also multiple cases to use чашка in technics, as a kind of round detail. This use is to be specified separately for each kind of detail.

Answer (score -3):

A ***чашка*** is a part of a set (a set of containers for drinking tea and saucers).
The ***кружка*** is a cylindrical container, usually not placed on a saucer.